# Python, unable to convert input() to int()

Tags: python, integer, explicit

I am trying to convert input() data to int() with the following code:

```
prompt_text = "Enter a number: "
try:
  user_num = int(input(prompt_text))
except ValueError:
  print("Error")

for i in range(1,10):
  print(i, " times ", user_num, " is ", i*user_num)

even = ((user_num % 2) == 0)

if even:
  print(user_num, " is even")
else:
  print(user_num, " is odd")
```

I get the following odd error when I enter **asd2** for example:

```
Enter a number: asd2 Error 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "chapter3_ex1.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(i, " times ", user_num, " is ", i*user_num) 
NameError: name 'user_num' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add something like `quit()` to your `except ValueError`. right now your program doesn't stop execution on error.

Comment: Not entirely on point but you might want to consider using `raw_input()` and handling the validation parsing of the supplied value once you've got a string - https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input, `input()` does an `eval` of the supplied input, effectively "turning it into code". This is unsafe.

Comment: @Will The OP might be using Python3.

Comment: Ahh, yes, great point :)

Comment: Generally it's nice to give a more informative error message, and to allow the user another chance to enter correct input. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for some excellent examples.

Comment: sobolevn nailed it :)

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you are facing is that the interpreter raises the error in the `try` and executes the `except` block. After that it will start to execute everyline. This will throw the `NameError`

You can overcome that by putting the rest of the  program into the `else` block.

```
prompt_text = "Enter a number: "

try:
    user_num = int(input(prompt_text))  

except ValueError:
    print("Error")

else:
    for i in range(1,10):
      print(i, " times ", user_num, " is ", i*user_num)

    even = ((user_num % 2) == 0)

    if even:
      print(user_num, " is even")
    else:
      print(user_num, " is odd")
```

Quoting from the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

> The try ... except statement has an ***optional else clause***, which, when
>   present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that
>   must be ***executed if the try clause does not raise an exception***.

Another way is to use a *sentinel* value

```
prompt_text = "Enter a number: "
user_num = 0 # default value
try:
    user_num = int(input(prompt_text))
except ValueError:
    print("Error")
```

This will also work. However the results may not be as expected.

---

Protip - Use 4 spaces to indent

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the conversion to an `int`. `user_num` doesn't get a value if an exception is thrown, but it's used later.

```
prompt_text = "Enter a number: "
try:
  user_num = int(input(prompt_text)) # this fails with `asd2`
except ValueError:
  print("Error") # Prints your error

for i in range(1,10):
  print(i, " times ", user_num, " is ", i*user_num) # user_num wasn't assigned because of the error

even = ((user_num % 2) == 0)

if even:
  print(user_num, " is even")
else:
  print(user_num, " is odd")
```

You can fix this by putting the code that uses `user_num` in the try-block. I'll also add create a function to clean things up.

```
def is_even(num):
  return num%2 == 0

prompt_text = "Enter a number: "
try:
  user_num = int(input(prompt_text))
  for i in range(1,10):
    print(i, " times ", user_num, " is ", i*user_num)
  if is_even(user_num):
    print(user_num, " is even")
  else:
    print(user_num, " is odd")
except ValueError:
  print("Error")
```

See the ideone [here](https://ideone.com/zZyzez).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the cleanest solution but it addresses the problem, in your code user_num is not initialized unless it is a number.

```
prompt_text = "Enter a number: "
user_num = "no Input"
try:
  user_num = int(input(prompt_text))
except ValueError:
  print("Error")

if str(user_num).isnumeric():
  for i in range(1,10):
    print(i, " times ", user_num, " is ", i*user_num)

  even = ((user_num % 2) == 0)

  if even:
    print(user_num, " is even")
  else:
    print(user_num, " is odd")
else:
  print("You did not enter a number")
```

Comment: I wouldn't think that it would be a good idea to again check in an `if` condition. The other answers have shown the better way AFAIK. It is easier and cleaner to put everything in the `try` block.